# Finding the energy over the capacitor in DC

Tags: capacitor, resistance, thevenin, norton

[image]

I tried using Thevenin to solve this and found Rth = 3 and Vth = 12 but this is way off the correct energy of the capactor (the energy is 4J).

Comment: This is homework, please provide an attempt at a solution (as per the site guidelines)

Comment: How is the homework question worded?  Why do you think that Thenenin source transformations apply?  Do you know how to calculate the energy in a capacitor?  Do units of energy match units of voltage or resistance?  If not, how do they answer the question?

Comment: By finding the thevenin voltage i would be finding v0 which is the open circuit of the capacitor and I could do 1/2*C*V^2, and @laptop2d this is not homework but a practice exercise.

Comment: @O.Sinno doesn't matter, we can't tell the difference, you still need to provide an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide a simplification of the schematic to get you started:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2UIIA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that there is no possible need to worry about where one end of ***VCCS1*** is connected. In your schematic, one end is tied to \$+12\:\text{V}\$. But that's irrelevant. So it's better to just leave it unconnected so you don't get confused about dealing with something that isn't relevant to the problem.

Now, you can see that I've also Thevenized your resistor divider to make things somewhat simpler. In fact, it's now so simple that you can solve it for the steady state ***VO*** (at \$t=+\infty\$) very quickly.

Of course, this also assumes that once you have ***VO*** that you know how to compute the capacitor energy from it. But the equation is everywhere, so I don't mind including it here for convenience:

$$w=\frac12 C V^2$$

As you can see, the voltage is squared here so both positive and negative voltage values will produce positive energy values (assuming the capacitance is also positively-valued, of course!)